# Exported SVG file rendered differently in browsers

Tags: css, google-chrome, svg, dc.js

I'm having problems in understanding what causes [this file](https://rawgit.com/amergin/8d00245edbb074bbcbad/raw/e5066f6bec1b4b18c5d5c3dde5367e62aeec9105/dc-js-exported-with-crowbar2.svg) to be rendered differently in browsers (Chrome: only axes visible, Safari and FF display the main content and axes).

It's a figure that has been exported from [DC.js example page](http://dc-js.github.io/dc.js/), first figure, using [SVG-crowbar2](https://github.com/NYTimes/svg-crowbar).

Basically the Crowbar just looks for any external css rules applied to the SVG element and applies them as inline css. The question is what css rules cause the elements to be shown differently?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue appears to be cause by the `#yearly-bubble-chart-clip > rect` element. It has inline styles that set `width` and `height` to `auto`. In Chrome, this is overriding the `width` and `height` attributes, and resulting in a clipping path that is `0` pixels by `0` pixels.

If you remove those styles, like so, it will work in Chrome.

```
<rect width="888" height="198" transform="translate(-0, -0)" style="overflow-x:visible;overflow-y:visible;perspective-origin:0px 0px;-webkit-perspective-origin:0px 0px;transform-origin:0px 0px;-webkit-transform-origin:0px 0px;"/>
```

[**JSFiddle Example**](https://jsfiddle.net/Lnwg4pgc/)

Answer (score 3):

Your `chart-body` seems to appear in Chrome if you remove the `width:auto;` and `height:auto;` from the `rect` in the `yearly-bubble-chart-clip` clip path.